# An unbounded sequence in a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I just need a sanity check. Can someone verify this proof for me?

> **Theorem**: Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space, and $x_n$ is an unbounded sequence. Then, there exists some $f \in X^*$, the topological dual, such that $f(x_n)$ is unbounded.

*Proof.* Suppose that $f(x_n)$ is bounded for all $f \in X^*$. Then, the set $\lbrace \widehat{x}_n \rbrace \in X^{**}$ has the property that $\widehat{x}_n(f)$ is bounded for all $f \in X^*$. By the Uniform Boundedness Principle on the complete space $X^*$, $\lbrace \widehat{x}_n \rbrace$ must be bounded. Since the canonical embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$ is an isometry, $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ is also bounded.

In particular, I just want to be certain that the completeness of $X$ is not required here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. In particular, there is no need to suppose that $X$ is a Banach space.