# Sequence in B* space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a $B^* $ space ,which means a normed vector space (not need to be complete),and $\{x_n\},n=1,2,3\dots$ is a sequence in $X$. And for all bounded  linear functional $f$,the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is bounded,try to prove that $\{x_n\}$ is therefore bounded.

I made some attempts. I try to show that if $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded ,then there must exist an  $f\in X^*$,such that  $\{f(x_n)\}$  is not bounded. I do see a proof ,as this [An unbounded sequence in a normed linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2758835).However this proof involes $X^{**}$ space and the corresponding embedding of it.These are given in the next charpter in my text book.And the charpter this problem in is about Hahn-Banach Theorem. I try to construct an linear space of $X$ via the condition of "unbounded" and apply this theorem to it.But I failed .I cannot find out  any property of this problem related with this theorem.

Hints will be wellcomed! Please do not post a full proof of this problem,appreciation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the double dual is to use the fact that the dual space of a normed space is a Banach space together with the uniform boundedness principle.
Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $X$.
Consider the map $T_n:X^*\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$T_n(f)=f(x_n),\qquad (f\in X^*)$$
By hypothesis, for every $f$, there exists some constant such that
$$|T_n(f)|=|f(x_n)|\leq C_f$$
Therefore, by the uniform boundedness principle, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that
$$\sup_n\|T_n\|\leq C$$
This means that for every $f\in X^*$ one has
$$\sup_n \sup \{|f(x_n)|: \|f\|=1\}\leq C$$
which (follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem), is the same as saying that
$$\sup_n\|x_n\|\leq C$$
i.e., the sequence is bounded.